Is there a way to subtract a credit from an aggregate sum in a SQL query?
I am creating a report in ColdFusion that is like a check register. Currently, I have summed the amounts by check number; however, if there is a credit applied to that same check number it is showing as another record. To comply with the way that the report was requested I need to be able to show only one record per check number with the appropriate amount.
Amount data is stored in the amount column of the table as a float. The credit is actually entered as -25 in the table. The chckDate, payee, and rtCode column values all identical for the line with the credit.



rtCode
checkNo
payee
amount




RP
1234
Charlie Brown
3063


RP
1234
Charlie Brown
-25



Check # XXXX $3063.00
Check # XXXX ($25.00)
It should show only Check # XXXX $3038
<cfquery name="checkListSum" datasource="xxx">
    select distinct checkno, sum(amount) as checkReportSum, chckDate, payee, rtCode
      from table
     where year(chckDate) = #checkYear#
       and month(chckDate) = #checkMonth#
  group by checkNo, chckDate, payee, rtCode
  order by chckDate

This is the query that I am using to pull the information from the table, however, I don't know how to subtract the credit.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

is the -25 an amount on the row? if so, then it should be correctly added by the SUM() in your query.

If checkNo isn't the same for the line with the credit, this is your problem

Your data example should include chckDate values for every row.

You're grouping by chckDate, but don't show it. The issue is likely that chckDate is different. Or that the payees contain subtle differences such as whitespace.

Also, you shouldn't need to select distinct as you're already grouping.

you don't need distinct when you have group by + the issue is most likely with the date field, the cheque date may differ for these two entries hence group by is not working correctly and splitting it to two rows

If it's not clear what others are saying about chckDate and you are still needing guidance, update the question with sample data that includes that column as well as desired results from this sql and we can help you craft the sql to get there.

@Schwern The question says The chckDate, payee, and rtCode column values all identical

@Barmar if everything is identical it should work, as mentioned by other people in the community seems like a date issue since that's the only field not shown in the sample data but guess will know more once the data is shown

@Barmar I believe they believe that.

A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data and the expected result. Also add a tag for the dbms used. (Your query uses product specific functionality.)

Try run this query
select checkno, sum(amount) as checkReportSum, min(chckDate)chckDate
    ,min(payee)payee, min(rtCode) rtCode
from tableХ
where year(chckDate) = #checkYear#
  and month(chckDate) = #checkMonth#
group by checkNo
order by min(chckDate)

What kind of result will you get?

ValNik :) doing some sql as always! you forget Alias Naming for min(chckDate) and You forgot to give an alias to min(chckDate) in the SELECT clause.

I didn't understand that You forgot to give an alias. What alias in min(chckDate)chckDate forgotted?

it looks ok now...

SELECT  ... [ [ AS ] column_alias ].  AS is not mandatory. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

what about readability? what if I am new to SQL and I see your code for the first time... :(> "Aliases are used also to specify names for the results of expressions,"

Aliases are undoubtedly useful for readability. However, the syntax expr1 as alias1 and expr1 alias1 are allowed by the rules. And there is no lack of alias here. The alias is present in both versions. You can say that one form is better than the other - I won't argue here, it really is.
